# How to visualize XML SOAP envelope using Postman

Tags: xml, xpath, postman

I am trying to Visualize my SOAP envelope in Postman into a simple table using the docs provided [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/visualizer/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/8c305ec8c713aad07b14).

Here is what my payload looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:e0817ed7-6575-4b05-8af4-0aa66bc3a428</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:49866f4c-0c5f-4d8e-b11d-cc194878215b</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-a0a30316-f6c4-4a36-bb48-13af93f451c6">
                <wsu:Created>2020-03-11T17:14:16Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2020-03-11T17:19:16Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>83222ed5-75a0-4ac0-8bb3-e3f76fdf89f9</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
                <Properties>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>key</Name>
                        <Value>11223344</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>status</Name>
                        <Value>pending</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Properties>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
                <Properties>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>subscriberkey</Name>
                        <Value>334455</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>status</Name>
                        <Value>sync_failure</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Properties>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is what I have so far in my Test script:

```
var template = `
    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
            {{#each}}
                <td>{{header name}}</td>
        {{/each}}
        </tr>

        {{#each}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{value}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`;

// Set visualizer
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    // Pass the response body parsed as JSON as `data`
    response: pm.response.json()
});
```

What I'm trying to do is dynamically generate all the header columns from the `Results > Properties > Property > Name` and have the values rows propergate from `Results > Properties > Property > Value`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is it not currently erroring because the payload is xml and you're parsing it as JSON. Unless you're converting that in the script before the template.

Answer (score 2):

This is seriously horrible but it would create a table with the data you need and maybe you can refactor it after:

```
// Convert the XML to JSON
let jsonData = xml2Json(pm.response.text());
// A nasty looking reference to the Results array
let resultsArray = jsonData["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"].RetrieveResponseMsg.Results

// Handlebars syntax for displaying the keys/values you want  
var template = `
    <table style="background-color:white";>
        <tr style="background-color:#d1d1e7;">
        {{#each response}}
        {{#with Properties}}
            {{#each Property}}
                <td>{{Name}}</td>
            {{/each}}
        {{/with}}
        {{/each}}
        </tr>
        <tr>
        {{#each response}}
        {{#with Properties}}
            {{#each Property}}
                <td>{{Value}}</td>
            {{/each}}
        {{/with}}
        {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </table>
`;

pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    response: resultsArray
});
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is almost there, it appears all nodes are in _one_ row rather than multiple.

Comment: You would need to tweak the handlebars code to get it to loop where you need it. I don't know the full usecase and what you would like as an end result, hopefully this is getting you closer.